# What happens to stdout when a script runs a program?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have an embedded application that I want a simple-minded logger for.

The system starts from a script file, which in turn runs the application. There could be various reasons that the script fails to run the application, or the application itself could fail to start. To diagnose this remotely, I need to view the stdout from the script and the application.

I tried writing a tee-like logger that would repeat its stdin to stdout, and save the text in a FIFO for later retrieval via the network. Then I naively tried

```
./script | ./logger
```

I ended up with only the script stdout going to the logger, and the application stdout disappearing. I had similar results trying tee.

The system is running kernel 2.4.26, and busybox.

What is going on, and how can I accomplish my desired ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was working exactly as I thought it should work, with one minor gotcha. stdout was being buffered, and without any fflush(stdout) commands, I never saw it. Had I been really patient, I would have suddenly seen a big gush of output when the stdout buffer filled up. A call to setlinebuf(3) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the application output doesn't end up on stdout...

1. The output is actually on stderr (which is usually *also* connected to the terminal)

   ```
      ./script.sh 2>&1 | ./logger
   ```

   should then work
2. The application actively disconnects from stdin/stdout (e.g. by closing/reopening file descriptors 0,1(,2) or, using `nohup`, `exec` or similar utilities)
3. the script daemonizes (which also detaches from all standard streams)

Comment: 1. I just tried that. It didn't help. There may be some stderr, but most of the output is to stdout.  2. I don't think I do any of that. 3. No daemons. Threads, yes. I don't see anything from the original thread.